# Swizzling Copy method of UIResponder

Tags: ios, objective-c, swizzling

I am swizzling Copy: and Paste: method of UIResponder.
I have to write the copied content to a private pasteboard.

```
- (void)copyToPrivatePasteboard:(id)sender
{
    UIPasteboard *privatePasteboard = [self getPrivatePasteboard];
    [privatePasteboard setString:@""];//How to get the copied string to store in pasteboard.
}
```

How can i write copied string to pasteboard. The parameter i am getting is of type id. 
If i convert it to NSString, it won't be proper because it is the sender who is calling this method (UIMenuController).

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? What methods are you swizzling? What are they doing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you want to replace `UIResponder's` `-copy:` with the code in you Q. (And doing the same thing with `-paste:`.)

This is the answer to your Q. But there are some comments at the end:

- If you swizzle a method, self will point to the receiver of the message. In your case it is the instance of `UIResponder`. So you have to grab the data using `self`. How can you do this? Not in general, because:
- `-copy:` can contain more than "Put my data to the pasteboard." It is a method. The code there can deal with other things you cannot not know. So you cannot substitute it that easy.
- Because of this `-copy:` is typically overwritten in subclasses. (I think, that it does nothing in its `UIResponder` implementation.) Swizzling `-copy:` in `UIResponder` will not change any behaviour in an instance of a subclass. Are you familiar with the concept of the [responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW2)?

Probably there are better ways to accomplish your goal:

- If you really want to do some swizzling, because it is cool, I would prefer [`+generalPasteboard`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIPasteboard/generalPasteboard) (`UIPasteboard`).
- Butmaybe you should describe your final goal with more details. Probably there is a completly different way to reach it.

Comment: If i understand, by default, all the copied content in the app or outside the app are written to generalPasteboard.

Comment: What i am trying to do is, inside the app if anything is copied or pasted it should go through my private pasteboard. So, whenever i copy something in my app it should by written to my Private Pasteboard not to the generalPasteboard. The reason i am using Copy: method is, whenever we copy something in the app, this method will be called. How could i achieve this better?

Comment: As I said in my answer: To me it seems to be easier, if you swizzle +generalPasteboard and deliver a custom subclass.

Comment: If i swizzle +generalPasteboard then i will disturb the general pasteboard. That i don't want to be. I need general pasteboard also.

Comment: This is worse than "disturbing" the whole UIResponder hierarchy and responder chain? Of course you should derive a subclass and call super in your code.